# Procedures for production C2DM issues

Tags: android, android-c2dm

The app which i worked is now in Google Market.

How we will identify and report possible production problems to Google?

Please let me know any URLs to report Production issues to GOOgle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The app which i worked is now in Google Market.

C2DM is not production-grade at this time, as it is still part of Google Labs.

> How we will identify and report possible production problems to Google?

I have no idea how you will identify them. That is up to you.

If you have questions regarding C2DM, here is the [relevant Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would respond to the email that was sent to you when you signed up for your C2DM account and which you used to request your production C2DM quota.  The original email would have been from android-c2dm@google.com